# How do I copy my class library assemblies to my Web project at build time?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, onion-architecture

**The Question**
How do I copy my class library assemblies to my Core Mvc project at build time?

**The Problem Statement**
I am working on porting an Onion Architecture project to Asp.Net Core. In line with the design approach, I have the following:

```
Some.Bootstrapper
- Startup.cs
Some.WebApi
- Program.cs
```

In Program.cs, I am referencing the Bootstrapper assembly to call my Starup.cs file:

```
.UseStartup("Some.Bootstrapper")
```

However, I am unable to figure out how to output the Bootstrapper assembly files to my WebApi project. [According to Onion](http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/the-onion-architecture-part-1/), I should not be making a direct reference to Some.Bootstrapper from Some.WebApi. In my previous Asp.Net project, I used the properties window of my Bootstrapper project to set the output path (e.g: ..\Some.WebApi\bin\". However, in Asp.Net Core, I understand that [I won't be able to set the output path until we move to msbuild](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/2902). It seems [this guy](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/5222) has been able to skin the cat. I am not exactly sure how.

**Expected Behavior**
I should be able to call .UseStartup("Some.Bootstrapper") without making a direct assembly reference.

Feedback appreciated.

Comment: Don't overdo it, unless it's a module that should be discovered as it gets dropped in, just reference it. Your WebApi project is the main application, the composition root. It's okay for it to register/reference all other assemblies of your project. Just other layers (domain, DAL) shouldn't have references to i.e. infrastructure, data access layer or application layer. You will just make your life harder trying to do this kind of stunts within the main application

Comment: Thanks Tseng. Understood and agreed. I should have clarified that my Startup.cs does reference numerous modules for Autofac IoC stuff. This is the main point - it is why don't want to take a direct reference between WebApi and Bootstrapper. I think I have sorted this. I'll post the update shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, using a post-compile script in my Bootstrapper project to xcopy my DLLs to WebApi was the best solution for me.

```
"scripts": {
    "postcompile": [ 
      "xcopy /I /F /Y %compile:OutputDir%\\. ..\\Some.WebApi\\bin\\%compile:Configuration%\\netcoreapp1.0\\" ]
  }
```

Credit goes to Binoy in [this thread](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/5222)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the System.Reflection.Assembly namespace

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("MyNice.dll");

Type type = assembly.GetType("MyType");

object instanceOfMyType = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Before I try that - doesn't the assembly have to be in the calling project's /bin folder?

Comment: no, you just need the path to the assembly, not necessarily in the bin folder. I.e 
Assembly.LoadFrom($"path\MyNice.dll");